# Why does this bitmap-manipulation code subtract the width from the stride?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

What does the line `imagePointer1 += bitmapData1.Stride - (bitmapData1.Width * 4);` mean in the following code?

```
var width = bitmap.Width;
var height = bitmap.Width;

var horizontalProjection = new double[width];
var verticalProjection = new double[height];

var bitmapData1 = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        unsafe
        {
            var imagePointer1 = (byte*)bitmapData1.Scan0;

            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    var blu = imagePointer1[0];
                    var green = imagePointer1[1];
                    var red = imagePointer1[2];

                    int luminosity = (byte)(((0.2126 * red) + (0.7152 * green)) + (0.0722 * blu));

                    horizontalProjection[x] += luminosity;
                    verticalProjection[y] += luminosity;

                    imagePointer1 += 4;
                } 

               imagePointer1 += bitmapData1.Stride - (bitmapData1.Width * 4);
            }
        }

        MaximizeScale(ref horizontalProjection, height);
        MaximizeScale(ref verticalProjection, width);

        var projections = 
            new[]
                {
                    horizontalProjection, 
                    verticalProjection
                };

        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData1);
        return projections;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is simply incrementing the pointer contained in the variable `imagePointer1`.

The reason you have to increment by the stride - (width * 4) is because of the way bitmaps are represented in memory.

There's a very comprehensive explanation available as part of [Bob Powell's GDI+ FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx).

Comment: It's actually just to compensate for the fact the internal loop is already doing +4 for skipping over each individual pixel. I generally solve this in a less messy way by using a new variable for the internal loop that initialises on the current value of `imagePointer1` for each new line.